# How to check if a variable is empty on command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have the following shell script

```
echo "please enter user name: "
read USER_NAME

while [ ! "$USER_NAME" ]
do
echo "User name can't be empty please re-enter: "
read USER_NAME
done
```

How can I do the same using commands on command line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061036/how-to-find-variable-is-empty-or-in-shell-script

Comment: Anything that works in a script works on the command line (at least I can not think of an exception right now). So just type it on the command line. The commandline essentially just prompts you to enter a shell script line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `while [ "$USER_NAME" == "" ] ...` or `while [ -z $USER_NAME ]`.